# Save data from one component to other component

Tags: angular, typescript

I have calendar with modal window, which allow to add events for any day of calendar. I have this written data showing in console but I can't bind it to save written data to calendar cells

Here is my code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nxczn8

By clicking on "save event" button data should be dispayed in calendar cell.
How I can reach that?

Comment: You'll most likely need to implement a service to communicate between you components: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

Comment: I added service but still I don't get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved your problems. If you need to show events when month changed, you need to store it on your service or component. Also you can check edited [StackBiltz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tpftym)

*on your app.component.ts*

```
weeks: Array<Array<{date: Date, hasEvent: boolean, eventTitle: string}>>;

  getEvents() {
    this.calendar.setDate(this.date);
    console.log(this.calendar.getWeeks());
    this.weeks = this.calendar.getWeeks().map(x => { return x.map(y => { return {date: y, hasEvent: false, eventTitle: ""} }) });
    const from = this.calendar.getFrom();
    const to = this.calendar.getTo();
  }

  openModalContent(weekIdx, day) {
    const  modalRef = this.modalService.open(ModalContentComponent);
    modalRef.result.then((result) => {
      day.hasEvent = true;
      day.eventTitle = result;
      console.log("result -> ", result);
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
  }
```

*on your app.component.html*

```
<tbody>
<tr *ngFor="let week of weeks; let weekIdx = index">
  <td *ngFor="let day of week" class="day-of-month" [ngClass] = "{'bg-primary': day.hasEvent}">
    <div class="events">
      <span class="day-number">{{ day.date | date:'d' }}</span>
      <button (click)="openModalContent(weekIdx, day)" class="btn-add">Add event</button>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```